# DNS benchmark and namebench on ubuntu return different results

Tags: 16.04, networking, dns, benchmarks

I have queried [DNS Benchmark](https://www.grc.com/dns/benchmark.htm) to find a list of DNS servers that are possibly faster than my ISP's. It is the first time at all I use this tool and the results are a bit confusing:

[image]

I have also run the [namebench](http://www.upubuntu.com/2011/08/choose-fastest-dns-servers-with.html) to compare the results, and it finds [different nameservers](http://file:///tmp/namebench_2018-07-14_2317.html).

How should I understand these outputs?

EDIT: what can I do to raise the attention to this question? It seems to me well posed and with all necessary details.